# sudo redirection doesn't work when in a function

Tags: bash, function, here-document

I have a script which writes some content into a file with `cat` and `EOF`. While this thing works within a bash script, it doesn't work if I put it inside a function.

**Working code**:

```bsh
cat << EOF | sudo tee /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
EOF
```

It's syntax highlighting (which seems fine);

[image]

**Not working code**:

```bsh
function someFunctions {
    cat << EOF | sudo tee /etc/network/interfaces
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet dhcp
    EOF
}

someFunctions
```

This one's syntax highlighting (which doesn't seem fine);

[image]

My editor (Atom) shows everything as green, which means it loses it's syntax highlighting but I couldn't find what's wrong.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the syntax highlighting the only indication that something is wrong? The function works AFAICT, so the problem does not seem to be with bash. If that is the case, I would complain to the Atom people.

Comment: As I've stated, the script is not working as well so it's not about syntax highlighting. I just showed that cuz I thought maybe it would mean something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `EOF` here-doc marker *must* either be at the beginning of the line, or a full TAB character indented:

```
someFunctions {
        sudo tee /etc/network/interfaces <<-'EOF'
        auto lo
        iface lo inet loopback

        auto eth0
        iface eth0 inet dhcp
        EOF
}
```

I've removed the `function` keyword as it's deprecated, and the `cat` as it adds no value. I've also used `<<-'EOF'` (instead of `<<EOF`) so that leading TAB characters are stripped, and the content of the here-doc is not evaluated for variables and other substitutions. If you want variable substitution don't quote the `EOF`, and use `<<-EOF` instead.

Comment: Thanks @roaima, this definitely works. But it doesn't support variables tho. Is there way to add variable support to this?